# DNS requests from a local server to another local server

Tags: iptables, routing, local-area-network

I have two servers running in one network.

External IP of main server: 1.2.3.4 (domain.com)

External IP of secondary server: should not be available directly from outside

Main server (dns, mx, www) internal address 10.10.10.10
Secondary server(www) - internal address 10.10.10.20
10.10.10.10 is also a default route for 10.10.10.20

**The task:**

```
(10.10.10.20)# dig @1.2.3.4 domain.com mx
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

(10.10.10.20)# dig @10.10.10.10 domain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-18.el7_1.1 <<>> @10.10.10.10 domain.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36417
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.com.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.com.              256     IN      A       1.2.3.4
```

The same query run from 10.10.10.10 works just fine

What happens here is that a server from local IP address (10.10.10.20) is trying to contact another server on its external IP address (1.2.3.4 or 10.10.10.10).

I am confused how should I handle this with iptables if I want to access external services of a main server from secondary server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand, you say 1.2.3.4 should not be available from the outside and it doesn't seem to be (hence the timeout). Do you want 1.2.3.4 to work locally on the 10.10.10.20 machine?

Comment: Secondary server is not supposed to have a direct access from network to server. Server is used for internal services. When I try to access services on a main server to its external IP (from a secondary server) I get timeouts. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have come up so far is:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 10.10.10.20 -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 10.10.10.20 -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:53
```

the same rules goes for other services if any.

So far I have not met any pitfalls and it works, so I will be marking this as a correct answer for now.